# Connection failed! Error - unsupported URL

Tags: iphone, xcode

I´m trying to make a login with name and password and pass it to a Url, but my connection fail and give me this error. What am I doing wrong?

Connection failed! Error - unsupported URL proyecto.lavidapirata.es/main/validate_credentials/

This is my method:

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{

    NSString *uName = userName.text;
    NSString *uPass = userPass.text;

    if([userName.text isEqualToString:@""] || [userPass.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        greeting.text = @"Input Your Value";
        //[userName resignFirstResponder];
        //[userPass resignFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    NSString *post =
    [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"uname=%@&pwd=%@",uName,uPass];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                         allowLossyConversion: YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@
                            "%d",[postData length]];


    //Parte de la petición
    NSURL *url =
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://proyecto.lavidapirata.es"];
    //proyecto.lavidapirata.es/main/validate_credentials
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                      initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else 
    {

    }

    //[userName resignFirstResponder];
    //[userPass resignFirstResponder];
    userName.text = nil;
    userPass.text = nil;    


}
```

that´s my console:

2011-05-26 11:50:32.856 PruebaPush[764:207] -[NSCFString setLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4bac460
2011-05-26 11:50:32.861 PruebaPush[764:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString setLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4bac460'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dcb5a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f1f313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00dcd0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d3c966 __*forwarding*** + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d3c522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   PruebaPush                          0x00003320 -[FirstViewController connection:didReceiveResponse:] + 111
    6   Foundation                          0x0005c3d0 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidReceiveResponse:] + 143
    7   Foundation                          0x0005c306 _NSURLConnectionDidReceiveResponse + 146
    8   CFNetwork                           0x013730cc _ZN19URLConnectionClient29_clientSendDidReceiveResponseEP14_CFURLResponsePNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 46
    9   CFNetwork                           0x0143f7ec _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 560
    10  CFNetwork                           0x0143f9cf _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 1043
    11  CFNetwork                           0x0136ac84 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
    12  CFNetwork                           0x0136aad3 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 251
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00dac8ff **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0a88b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00d09d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d09840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d09761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x017221c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x01722289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x002c9c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  PruebaPush                          0x00002778 main + 102
    22  PruebaPush                          0x00002709 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: Are you sure that's the same code you're using? From your error it looks like you're missing the http:// off the front.

Answer (score 0):

the error means the url which is using is wrong.Check your url address

Comment: The URL works, now I changed that for lavidapirata.es/main/validate_credentials/ where i supposed i have to write my name and password, but when now I do that it response me with html code, so I don´t know what´s wrong, and my questions is I have to do something specific in the webservice code?